# zxing doesn't handle null properly

Tags: android, zxing

The error message that zxing should show if the result is null doesn't come up. What do I need to change? My code is here:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);


    if (scanningResult != null) {
                //we have a result
                scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
                scanFormat = scanningResult.getFormatName();


                formatTxt.setText("FORMAT: " + scanFormat);
                contentTxt.setText("CONTENT: " + scanContent);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please click 'Update DataBase' after this message ends", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No scan data received. Restart the scanner", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
```

No matter what the result, the 'Please Click' toast keeps appearing.

As per the answer, I have tweaked my code to the following:

```
// retrieve scan result
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        //String contents = null;
        //IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            //we have a result
            if (resultCode ==RESULT_OK){
                scanContent = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
                scanFormat = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
                formatTxt.setText("FORMAT: " + scanFormat);
                contentTxt.setText("CONTENT: " + scanContent);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please click 'Update DataBase' after this message ends", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No scan data received. Restart the scanner", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }       
    }
```

While there don't appear to be any syntax errors, the scanning doesn't display any output.

Comment: Use nested if's "if (requestCode == 0)" and "if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)"

Answer (score 0):

You should use `onActivityResult` like this

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
String contents = null;
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if (requestCode == 0) {
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
         contents = data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
         String format = data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
         //moved here
         TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scanResult);
         tv.setText(contents);
         // Handle successful scan
      } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
         // Handle cancel
      }
}
```